# Не подключается локальная служба по net.tcp

Tags: c#, wcf

Пробую работать с WCF. Создал службу, и хочу в клиенте ее добавить (Добавить ссылку на службу -> вставляю адрес). Но почему-то выдает ошибку. Службы все на localhost. Сторонние службы из интернета добавляет нормально. Перед добавлением уже службу запустил даже. Если в клиенте создать фабрику, то служба работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код службы (реализуется интерфейс в котором один метод string Get(string city); для теста)

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Сервис погоды";
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

        Uri address = new Uri("net.tcp://127.0.0.1:6000/Icontract");        // ADDRESS
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();                        // BINDING
        Type construct = typeof(IWtServiceContract);                        // CONTRACT; 
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(CitiesWheather));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(construct, binding, address);

        try
        {
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Сервис запущен!");
        }

        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
            host.Close();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Дак а серверная часть у вас точно запущена?

Comment: Да. Отредактировал свой вопрос, добавил скриншот. Там у меня три сервиса сразу запущенны. с портами 6000/6001/6002

Comment: Разве имя вебсервиса не должно там заканчиваться на .svc к примеру?

Comment: Для того что бы `VS` смогла сгенерировать `proxy-класс` ей нужно помочь. Проверьте, что конфиге сервера в узле `behaviors/serviceBehaviors/behavior` создан узел `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled = "true"/>`

Comment: И вообще, при подобных вопросах желательно прикладывать файл конфигурации, как сервера так и клиента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Студия использует специальный протокол для получения метаданных сервиса - WS-MEX. Как я вижу, вы его в своем контракте IWtServiceContract не реализовали - потому студия и не может ничего сделать.

К счастью, реализовывать его и не надо - достаточно добавить дополнительную конечную точку, где вы будете публиковать метаданные.

Для начала, понадобится добавить вашей службе ServiceMetadataBehavior:

```
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior());
```

Теперь можно добавлять конечные точки:

```
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(), "net.tcp://127.0.0.1:6000/Icontract/mex");
```

Отмечу, что адрес конечной точки для публикации метаданных не может совпадать с основным адресом, потому что у них разные привязки - но по соглашению можно добавить в конец URI "/mex". Студия достаточно умная чтобы добавлять этот суффикс самостоятельно при попытке создания клиента.

Тем не менее, ничто не мешает использовать совершенно другой URI или даже другой протокол. Например, можно опубликовать метаданные по HTTP вот так:

```
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "http://127.0.0.1/Icontract");
```

Также можно вместо использования WS-MEX использовать WSDL. Для этого у ServiceMetadataBehavior есть свойства HttpGetEnabled и HttpGetUrl:

```
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior
{
    HttpGetEnabled = true,
    HttpGetUrl = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1/Icontract"),
});
```

В этом случае страницу `http://127.0.0.1/Icontract` можно будет открыть из браузера и увидеть там WSDL-описание. Студия также умеет генерировать клиент по такому описанию. А если дописать в конец URL параметр `?singleWsdl` - то такое описание можно будет скачать в виде одного файла и передать другому разработчику.

Все эти способы не являются взаимоисключающими - их можно использовать хоть все три вместе:

```
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior
    {
        HttpGetEnabled = true,
        HttpGetUrl = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1/Icontract"),
    });
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWtServiceContract), binding, "net.tcp://127.0.0.1:6000/Icontract");
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(), "net.tcp://127.0.0.1:6000/Icontract/mex");
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "http://127.0.0.1/Icontract");
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за развернутый и профессиональный ваш ответ!!!

Comment: Все работает, еще раз огромное спасибо!